# How to prove this fact of congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let be N an integer congruent to $344 \pmod {559}$

Is it always true that $(N \pmod {22919}) \pmod {344}$ is equal to either 0 or 215 and how to prove it if true? 
Example $69660 \equiv 344 \pmod {559}$

$(69660 \pmod {22919} )\pmod {344}$ is 215.

Another example is N=541456

$(541456 \pmod {22919}) =14319$, then
$14319 \pmod {344}=215$

Comment: Note:
$$
344 = 2^3 \cdot 43, \quad 
559 = 13\cdot 43, \quad 
22919 = 29 \cdot 79.
$$

Comment: Keep in mind that you are interpreting "mod" as referring to a binary operation. That is, $N \bmod 22919$ is an integer in this context.  Under the usual mathematical interpretation, the expression $(N \pmod {22919}) \pmod {344}$ is not well defined.

Comment: Yes it is an integer

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave this context.  For instance, how did you come across this "fact"? Why do you suspect that it is true?

Comment: It is related to a precedent question

Comment: The phrase "a precedent question" doesn't make sense. Presumably you mean that this is related to your [previous question over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3563137/81360). Your other question is also very mysterious; is there a reason you suspect that this other statement holds?

Comment: It seems to be so

Comment: I understand that that you have numerical evidence for the result, but this is not helpful in giving us ideas of how to think of the problem.  My question is how did you decide that this other fact might be worth testing in the first place?

Comment: Re: your deleted comment- you said nothing about probable primes in the previous post.  How did you decide that the expressions from your previous post are probable primes?  How exactly did you come up with those expressions?  Is this related to some existing paper or method?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom.- $22919=13\cdot41\cdot43$. Best regards.

Comment: @Piquito thanks for the correction

Comment: Some possibly helpful observations:
$$
N = 344 \pmod{559} \iff 
43 \mid N \text{ and }
N = 6 \pmod{13}\\
M = 0 \pmod {344} \iff 43\mid M \text{ and } 8 \mid M
\\
M = 215 \pmod{344} \iff 43\mid M \text{ and } M = 7 \pmod{8}.
$$

Comment: The answer is no.  For instance, take $N = 1462$.

Comment: WARNING.- $541456=22\cdot22919+7238$ the second example is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  For instance, $N = 344 + 2 \cdot 559 = 1462$ leads to 
$$
(1462 \bmod {22919} )\bmod {344} = 86.
$$

Comment: I was expecting your answer. It is clear that the equation $$N=559x+344=22919y+Z$$ has an infinity of integer solutions so there is some values of $Z$ distinct of $0,215$